# Ejecutar funcion cuando otra se complete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Estoy tratando de ejecutar una función cuando otra se complete pero a parte de que no tengo ni idea de como hacerlo. Por el camino que voy me da error de sintaxis y no entiendo muy bien el motivo.

esta es la forma que estoy tratando de hacerlo:

```
$.when( Ventanica('Articulos.php','Articulos','1100','700','Gestión de Articulos'); ).then(function() { VerMas('Inarticulos','Articulos','modificar','modificar_articulos',IdArticulo); });
```

Ventanica me abre un dialog de jquery ui y carga una web dentro y ver mas me abre el articulo en cuestión dentro de ese dialog.

¿Esta es la forma de hacerlo? solo ejecuta la primera funcion y de la segunda pasa olímpicamente

Comment: Elimina el ; en el parametro , `'Gestión de Articulos');` ...

Comment: Hace lo mismo @Einer

Comment: Y que paso? No funciono?

Comment: Tambien eliminalo de `IdArticulo);`

Comment: Si, da el mismo error. Pero son parámetros que necesita la función para funcionar... ¿elimino tambien el ");"

Answer (score 2):

Al usar [jQuery.when](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) la salida es un objeto `thenable` o sea una "promesa" (aunque las promesas de jQuery son un poco sui generis). Si invocas `when` pasándole un argumento que no devuelve una promesa o un [jQuery.Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Deferred), la primera parte del `when` se resuelve de inmediato.

Mira el siguiente ejemplo. Tenemos una función que retorna de inmediato. Usar `when` con ella ejecutará el `then` al instante.

Tenemos otra función que retorna una promesa, la cual se resuelve 2 segundos después, via un `setTimeout`. En el segundo caso, como la función devuelve una promesa, el `when` efectivamente se queda esperando a la resolución de la promesa.

```js
function imprime_inmediato() {
  var ahora=(new Date()).toISOString().split(/[T|\.]/)[1];
  console.log('retorno inmediato empieza a las',ahora);
}
function imprime_diferido(texto) {
  var d1 = $.Deferred();
  var ahora=(new Date()).toISOString().split(/[T|\.]/)[1];
  console.log('retorno diferido empieza a las',ahora);
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    d1.resolve();
  },2000);
  return d1.promise();
}


function terminado(tipo) {
  var ahora=(new Date()).toISOString().split(/[T|\.]/)[1];
  console.log(tipo,'terminado a las', ahora);
}

$.when(imprime_inmediato())
  .then(function() { 
    terminado('inmediato');  
   });
   
$.when(imprime_diferido())
  .then(function() { 
    terminado('diferido');  
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

En tu caso, lo que quieres es ejecutar `VerMas` cuando el popup haya terminado de cargar, de manera que `Ventanica` debiese decir algo como:

```
function Ventanica(url,windowName,ancho,alto) {
   var d1 = $.Deferred();

   newwindow=window.open(url,windowName,'height='+alto+',width='+ancho);

   newwindow.addEventListener('load',d1.resolve(), true); 

   return d1.promise();
 }
```

De ese modo, la función no retorna de inmediato, sino que retorna una promesa que se resuelve cuando el popup emite el evento `load`.

La sintaxis para llamar a las funciones sería:

```
$.when( Ventanica('Articulos.php','Articulos','1100','700','Gestión de Articulos') )
.then(function() { 
    VerMas('Inarticulos', 'Articulos', 'modificar', 'modificar_articulos', IdArticulo); 
});
```

Comment: Creo que lo entiendo... voy a intentar poner el deferred a ver si con eso lo consigo :) mil gracias por tu ayuda. Pruebo y te digo algo